# how to get android camera to work in multiple orientations

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-preferences, android-orientation

OK I have this camera code
I want to make it so that it will work in all orientations.
and on android 2.2/2.3.3/3.2

I was thinking something like

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 8)
do v8 work
else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 10)
do v10 work
else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 14)
do v14 work
```

but I'm not having any luck.
Everything I try fails.
Please help.

Activity.java

```
package com.ice_os.android.kamura;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class Activity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "Kamura";
    Camera camera;
    Preview preview;
    Button scan;
    Button preferences;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(camera != null)
        {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);
        scan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,
                        jpegCallback);
            }
        });
        preferences = (Button)findViewById(R.id.preferences);
        preferences.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent PreferencesIntent = new Intent(AllergyDetektive.this,Preferences.class);
                startActivity(PreferencesIntent);

            }

        });
        preview = new Preview(this);
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);



        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");

    }

    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
        }
    };

    /** Handles data for raw picture */
    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };

    /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                        "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        }
    };  

//  @Override
//  public void onPause(){
//      super.onPause();
//      camera.lock();
//      if(camera != null)
//      {
//          camera.release();
//          camera = null;
//      }
//      
//  }

}
```

Preview.java

```
package com.ice_os.android.kamura;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "Preview";

    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    public Camera camera;

    Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        camera = Camera.open();
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

            camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: "
                                + data.length);
                    }
                    finally {
                    }
                    Preview.this.invalidate();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
//        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8)
//              setDisplayOrientation(camera, 0);
//          else
//          {
//              if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
//              {
//                  parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
//                  parameters.set("rotation", 90);
//              }
//              if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
//              {
//                  parameters.set("orientation", "landscape");
//                  parameters.set("rotation", 90);
//              }
//          }  

        parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        parameters.set("orientation","landscape");
        parameters.set("rotation", 0);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        Paint p = new Paint(Color.RED);
        Log.d(TAG, "draw");
        canvas.drawText("PREVIEW", canvas.getWidth() / 2,
                canvas.getHeight() / 2, p);
    }

    protected void setDisplayOrientation(Camera camera, int angle){
        Method downPolymorphic;
        try
        {
            downPolymorphic = camera.getClass().getMethod("setDisplayOrientation", new Class[] { int.class });
            if (downPolymorphic != null)
                downPolymorphic.invoke(camera, new Object[] { angle });
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
        }
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ice_os.android.allergy_detektive"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" android:required="false"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Preferences" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

main.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/scan"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:background="@drawable/black_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/preferences"
    android:text="klick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/preferences"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:background="@drawable/black_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/preferences" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scan" >

</FrameLayout>
```

log.txt

```
02-25 08:33:30.623: D/Kamura(355): onCreate'd
02-25 08:33:32.012: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:32.362: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:32.593: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:32.952: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 930K, 55% free 3027K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 117ms
02-25 08:33:33.062: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:33.283: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 438K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 142ms
02-25 08:33:33.413: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:33.693: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 57ms
02-25 08:33:33.703: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:33.922: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 49ms
02-25 08:33:33.932: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:34.152: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 48ms
02-25 08:33:34.162: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:34.393: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 58ms
02-25 08:33:34.413: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:34.633: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 45ms
02-25 08:33:34.653: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:34.864: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 47ms
02-25 08:33:34.882: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:35.112: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 46ms
02-25 08:33:35.132: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:35.344: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 47ms
02-25 08:33:35.363: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:35.603: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 55ms
02-25 08:33:35.623: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:35.842: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 50ms
02-25 08:33:35.862: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:36.092: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 57ms
02-25 08:33:36.112: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:36.323: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 47ms
02-25 08:33:36.343: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:36.573: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 47ms
02-25 08:33:36.593: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:36.802: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 48ms
02-25 08:33:36.822: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:37.052: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 48ms
02-25 08:33:37.073: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:37.293: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 46ms
02-25 08:33:37.303: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:37.533: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 57ms
02-25 08:33:37.553: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:37.763: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 47ms
02-25 08:33:37.782: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:37.992: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 48ms
02-25 08:33:38.012: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:38.253: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 50ms
02-25 08:33:38.274: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:38.504: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 47ms
02-25 08:33:38.523: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:38.733: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 46ms
02-25 08:33:38.753: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:38.972: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 47ms
02-25 08:33:38.982: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:39.213: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 45ms
02-25 08:33:39.223: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:39.453: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 59ms
02-25 08:33:39.473: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:39.693: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 56ms
02-25 08:33:39.713: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:39.922: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 47ms
02-25 08:33:39.942: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:40.162: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 47ms
02-25 08:33:40.172: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:40.403: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 47ms
02-25 08:33:40.433: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:40.653: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 48ms
02-25 08:33:40.663: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:40.892: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 47ms
02-25 08:33:40.902: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:41.132: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 47ms
02-25 08:33:41.153: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:41.364: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 47ms
02-25 08:33:41.383: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:41.623: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 55ms
02-25 08:33:41.643: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:41.862: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 49ms
02-25 08:33:41.882: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:42.113: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 54ms
02-25 08:33:42.152: D/Preview(355): onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 447120
02-25 08:33:42.912: D/dalvikvm(355): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 436K, 56% free 3026K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 563ms
02-25 08:33:43.393: D/Kamura(355): onCreate'd
02-25 08:33:43.465: D/AndroidRuntime(355): Shutting down VM
02-25 08:33:43.465: W/dalvikvm(355): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-25 08:33:43.483: E/AndroidRuntime(355): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 08:33:43.483: E/AndroidRuntime(355): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
02-25 08:33:43.483: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.hardware.Camera.setHasPreviewCallback(Native Method)
02-25 08:33:43.483: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.hardware.Camera.access$600(Camera.java:114)
02-25 08:33:43.483: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:545)
02-25 08:33:43.483: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 08:33:43.483: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-25 08:33:43.483: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-25 08:33:43.483: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 08:33:43.483: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-25 08:33:43.483: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-25 08:33:43.483: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-25 08:33:43.483: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 08:33:46.753: I/Process(355): Sending signal. PID: 355 SIG: 9
```

Comment: whats fails?  in your manifest you are using  android:screenOrientation="landscape" make thats y?...

Comment: sorry i did that so it would not crash

Comment: Yes, what do you mean by fail?  Do you mean you are getting no preview, that the preview is distorted or wrong for certain orientations, or something else?

Comment: I mean it crashes I get no preview. I need to know how to set orientation on those 3 versions

Comment: If you want it to work across those versions you are going to have to lock the camera into landscape, it's a pretty well known issue. Those that state that 2.2 supports portrait and landscape are right and wrong in the it's completely device dependent.  I have multiple HTC devices on 2.3.4 that still won't support portrait.  Also post a logcat for the crash if you want help with that.

Comment: OK added Logcat to the question

Comment: OK I have decided to lock orientation. I did so by this in the manifest file  <activity
            android:name=".Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
             >        The error in log happens on exit of the program. something about method after .release();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for understanding:  camera itself is not aware of orientation, its CCD chip 
is firmly soldered to motherboard,  and raw picture provided by camera has origin in top left corner of phone held in landscape position,  with x direction to the right and y to the bottom - there is nothing that can change this fact.  It's up to you to process raw image to change its orientation.

And also keep in mind,  that when orientation changes,  your ativity is recreated and you have to handle camera properly:

- stop preview
- wait until surface view isreconfigured
- start preview again

PS:  when your phone is going to slep/lock screen, launcher can forcibly change orientation of layout even if you prohibited it .

Answer (score 2):

Your Specifying  android:screenOrientation="landscape" inur manifest file.so it may be running only in that orientation bcoz of that.dnt specify that.